# Delta function in the context of Gaussian processes

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, gaussian-process

I am learning gaussian processes from the book [Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/textbook/091117.pdf), Chapter 19, page 400, section 19.1.2. A snapshot from the text,
[image: snapshot_from_book]

I failed to understand the use of delta function here, why, the equation can't simply be written as,  $$p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x}) = \int_\mathbf{w} \mathbf{\Phi w} p(\mathbf{w})$$

Am I missing something trivial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is actually the following:
$$p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x})=\int p(\mathbf{y|\mathbf{x},\mathbf{w}})p(\mathbf{w})d\mathbf{w}$$
Here, $p(\mathbf{y|\mathbf{x},\mathbf{w}})$ is the distribution of $\mathbf{y}$ when we know $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{w}$, in which the relation is actually *deterministic*, i.e. $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{\Phi(x)}\mathbf{w}$. So, $\mathbf{y}$ can only be single value, whose distribution is represented by dirac-delta functions to be able to do further analysis. This deterministic relation is automatically enforced because the delta function will ensure that no $\mathbf{w}$ value will be integrated if $\mathbf{y}\neq \mathbf{\Phi(x)}\mathbf{w}$, since $\delta(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{\Phi(x)}\mathbf{w})$ is $0$ when the two are not equal. This is not the same as replacing $p(\mathbf{y|\mathbf{x},\mathbf{w}})$ with $\mathbf{\Phi(x)w}$.

Comment: So in other words we are taking a subset of $\mathbf{w}$'s that satisfied the condition =() , but is not it true that _whatever_ the **w** is y will always be equal to () ? That's how we wrote the equation, and created it deterministic.

Comment: () gives you a **y** but what if you ask for the density of another **y** given the same ,?

Comment: Ahh, I see, because it has to be joint distribution so all possible (x,y) combination has to be described. Thanks, I think I understand it now.